# Is there a language that supports a way to mark a parameter as not getting modified by a function?

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, language-features

In C# there are keywords that allow one to mark a parameter as a `ref`, `out`, or an ordinary parameter.

Are there any languages that support marking that a parameter being passed in won't be modified by that function?

If the parameter were a list and the function called clear() on the list, then in order for the language to know that the parameter wasn't changing, I guess such a language would also need a way of marking whether or not a method modified an object's internal state.

Comment: This is not about "modifying (ie. reassigning) a parameter", but about not modifying an *object*, which is independent of a parameter (being merely a binding/name). In a language like C# this is done by making the object non-mutable (although struct types are effectively copied) or otherwise explicitly declaring that mutation/non-mutation guarantee in the method contract; it might be as simple as taking an IEnumerable instead of an IList. C++ has `const`, which is the 'closest' thing I know of marking a method (on an object, not a parameter) as non-mutating.

Comment: `const` parameters in C++ seem to fit the bill... Also all functional languages implicitly have that assumption - so you can add most, if not all of them to the list.

Comment: Almost every language has cases where parameters can't be modified in any way. For example standard (primitive) parameters in C++ or primitive types in Java. Where (object-)references and pointers and all this stuff comes into play it looks a bit harder to achieve a complete constant behaviour. There are not many languages where you have that complete freedom to choose what you really hand to a function.

Comment: Side note: title asks for single language (and thus concrete answerable SO question - i.e. [Guffa's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32917478/477420)) while body asks for list (which likely too broad). Do you really need a list of you have more practical reason behind the question?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: - No there is no real need for the list it was simply a matter of curiosity.  I feel like having a keyword like `unchanging` would help make it clear the intent of the parameter as well as that of the function, but I can still code as usual without it.

Comment: @user2864740: Taking an IEnumerable can still be cast to it's original array / list and subsequesntly modified.

Comment: @user420667 what you going to cast `Enumerable.Range(1,100)` to (or any method that uses `yield return`)? Absolute guarantee that code will not modify arguments is essentially not possible if you allow to go outside contracts (i.e. by simply calling machine level code to change arguments). In C# one option of such contract is to use read-only interfaces (like `IEnumerable<T>` and immutable objects like `string`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Pascal you can specify a [constant parameter](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu63.html), which tells the compiler that the programmer won't change the parameter in the function.

Comment: The documentation explicitly talks about parameter reassignment and stack operations; if this is all it is then the preventing reassignment is similar a final parameter in Java (inside the method, nevermind the calling difference). The example then goes on to show how it prevents call by reference semantics; but for call by (object) sharing this doesn't necessarily sities matter.

Comment: I believe the question is about a guarantee that whatever object is passed,  in a languages that has call by sharing semantics, the object will not be altered - the question uses a mutable List as an example. This naturally doesn't apply to languages, or constructs within them,  without (shared/visible) mutations.

Comment: @user2864740: The question can be interpreted that way, but the answer clearly states what interpretation of the question it answers. Just because the answer doesn't answer your interpretation of the question doesn't make it wrong.